# how to lock an action in rails so that only one user can access it without use of a db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this weird situation where I want to restrict an action to only one user at a time without any use of db?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use class variables. Class variables last not only for one instance, they are the same in every instance of the class.

```
def do_something
  if @@locked
    render text: "Sorry, somebody else working here."
  else
    @@locked = true

    # do the stuff you need to do here

    @@locked = false
  end
end
```

Comment: That won't work if you deploy with say mongrel with multiple instances.  Each instance would have it's own @@locked variable. If you want to do it so it's deployment independent, you'd have to use the filesystem.  If you deploy on multiple hosts,  the filesystem where you create the lock would have to be shared between the hosts.

Answer (score 2):

```
require FileUtils
def lockable_action
  if File.exists? "/tmp/lock"
     # sorry, I'm locked
  else
     File.open("/tmp/lock","w") {|f| f.write("1")
     # do your thing
     FileUtils.rm "/tmp/lock"
  end
endk
```